Need to install onnxruntime 1.9 but cannot find a version that satisfies requirements
I get this error when trying to run pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu

user@computer AICoverGen % pip install onnxruntime
Requirement already satisfied: onnxruntime in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: coloredlogs in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from onnxruntime) (15.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from onnxruntime) (24.3.25)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from onnxruntime) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from onnxruntime) (24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from onnxruntime) (5.26.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from onnxruntime) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: humanfriendly>=9.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from coloredlogs->onnxruntime) (10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from sympy->onnxruntime) (1.3.0)

user@computer AICoverGen % pip install onnxruntime-gpu
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu

I am on macos 14.4.1
I am and have  to be on python 3.9
I tried running this with onnxruntime installed and without it installed, since I'm not sure how its supposed to go.

Any success with this? I'm having the same issue.

I am guessing you are running this on a mac. onnxruntime-gpu will not work on mac.
See https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/12252 and comment on No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu>=1.16.0 when installing Pyannote from GitHub.
In my requirements.txt I use:
onnxruntime-gpu; sys_platform != 'darwin'


Your error message shows you are using Python 3.10 but you mentioned you are on Python 3.9.
Do note that onnxruntime-gpu 1.9.0 and onnxruntime 1.9.0 requires Python 3.6 - 3.9.
If you want to use these packages, you may have to downgrade to a supported python version.

hey there! thanks so much for your reply
I had two installed versions 3.9 and 3.10, so I removed 3.10 (even though the current was marked as 3.9) but it still doesn't work
me@ ~ % pip3 install onnxruntime-gpu
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime-gpu
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

did you try using a virtual environment?

also try python -m pip install onnxruntime-gpu==1.9.0
